# File associations for pdfs keep getting set to open with Word

Tags: macos, ms-office, pdf

Not sure if it's a mac-specific problem (let me know if I should move it), but every time I try to open a pdf file, Microsoft Word tries (and fails) to open it. I have tried "open with..." > Preview with the "always open with" box checked on multiple occasions, and it works for a while, but by the next day it is always set back to opening with Word. Any ideas what the culprit could be?

Update: this seems to be happening with txt files too... I never try to open either pdfs or txt files in Word, so I'm not sure how it keeps getting reset...

Comment: the 'always open with' box you checked was accessed in Get Info?

Comment: I tried right-clicking and using "open with..." and also "Change all" within Get Info, neither seemed to stick...

Comment: I have this same issue. It is particularly irksome.

Comment: @Jules did you ever find a solution? Most irksome of all, no matter how many times I say 'open in Preview always,' Preview never stays on the short list of programs in the right-click 'open with' menu...

Comment: Not a repeatable fix. My Mac crashed last week. After that crash+restart, this issue went away. [shrug]